# Summarize delegated click event functions Jquery

Tags: jquery

I have several functions, click events delegated to a `.container` (this is generated dinamically)

```
    $('.Container').on('click', '.a', function(){$(document).Function1();});
    $('.Container').on('click', '.b', function(){$(document).Function2();});
    $('.Container').on('click', '.c', function(){$(document).Function3();});
    $('.Container').on('click', '.d', function(){$(document).Function4();});
    $('.Container').on('click', '.e', function(){$(document).Function5();});
    $('.Container').on('click', '.f', function(){$(document).Function6();});
```

It works well, but how do I summarize all those callings into a single `on("click"` event?

Comment: You really don't want to, given that your operation in the handler is different for each.  If you did you'd have to have a conditional for each class to know which method to execute.

Comment: The code in my answer had an error which I just fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML

```
<div data-fav-animal="pig"></div>
<div data-fav-animal="horse"></div>
<div data-fav-animal="cow"></div>
```

Jquery

```
$('.Container').on('click', '[data-fav-animal]', function()
{
    var myFav = $(this).data('fav-animal');
    WhichFunction(myFav);
});

function WhichFunction(faveAnimal){
    switch(faveAnimal) {
    case 'pig':
        doThis();
        break;
    case 'cow';:
        doThat();
        break;
    default:
        doThatOtherThing();
    } 
return;
}
```

Using something like a data attribute could give you more control. You could remove the letter classes and selector and use data attribute instead even.

Also could use Enums to eliminate all the hardcode strings.

```
$('.Container').on('click', '.a, .b, .c, .d, .e, .f', function()
{
    var myFav = $(this).data('fav-animal');
    WhichFunction(myFav);
});
```

If the classes must remain on the DOM elements.

```
var functionName = "blah";
window[functionName]();
```

Allows execute of a function in global scope, just by knowing its name. This would allow you to remove the switch in code above and retain/gain flexibility.

Comment: So, within the `(".container` click event would need to exists something like this?  `WhichFunction(myFav)`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in general following a pattern of.

```
$('.Container').on('click', '.a, .b', function(){
    var $this = $(this);

    if ($this.hasClass('a')) {
      //do something
    } else if ($this.hasClass('b')) {
      //do something
    }
});
```

The trade off being you've moved the conditional from the child selector into the logic itself.  Some might argue that this reduces readability and while I'm probably in that camp as well, this is indeed possible to do.

Answer (score 0):

This would kind of work:

```js
let elements = ['.a', '.b', '.c', '.d', '.e', '.f']

let funcs = {};

// create Function1...6
for (let i=0; i < elements.length; i++) {
  funcs['Function'+(i+1)] = function() { console.log(elements[i]); }
}

$('.Container').on('click', elements.join(', '), function(e) {
  funcs[`Function${(elements.indexOf('.'+e.target.className)+1)}`]()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="Container">
  <li class="a">a</li>
  <li class="b">b</li>
  <li class="c">c</li>
  <li class="d">d</li>
  <li class="e">e</li>
  <li class="f">f</li>
</ul>
```

Let me know if that is what you were looking for.